# SSIS Deadlock with a Slowly Changing Dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

I am running an SSIS package that contains many (7) reads from a single flat file uploaded from an external source. There is consistently a deadlock in every environment(Test, Pre-Production, and Production) on one of the data flows that uses a Slowly Changing Dimension to update an existing SQL table with both new and changed rows. 
I have three groups coming off the SCD[image: SSIS Data Flow]:

-Inferred Member Updates Output goes directly to an OLE DB Update command.

-Historical Attribute goes to a derived column boxed that sets a delete date and then goes to an update OLE DB command, then goes to a union box where it unions with the last group New Output.

-New Output goes into a union box along with the Historical output then to a derived column box that adds an update/create date, then inserts the values into the same SQL table as the Inferred Member Output DB Command.

The only error I am getting in my log looks like this:

**"Transaction (Process ID 170) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."**

I could put the (NOLOCK) statement into the OLE db commands, but I have read that this isn't the way to go.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Data Tools to investigate and edit the Package, but I am unsure where to go from here to find the issue.

I want to get out there that i am a novice in terms of SSIS programming... with that out of the way... Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it is just pointing me to a place I haven't looked for help.

Comment: Please post your SSIS package, default isolation level. Do you use transaction in SSIS?

Comment: Anyway Slow Changing Dimension is incredibly slow for bigger datasets. Consider using set based approach.

Comment: @lad2025 I am not allowed to post the package as it contains the connection strings and passwords... being a novice, i will try to recreate the data flow object that is having the issue.

Comment: I meant printscreen of control/data flow.

Comment: @lad2025 I added the snip screen of the data flow, for the second comment, I did not create this and therefore cannot change it  without an exact plan of why and how. Right now, i am unsure why it is deadlocking. Speed isn't the issue, because it is really only effecting one table and about 150-200 records a day.

Comment: @tCoe the key thing (if you want to recreate the issue) is data model and data itself. Please put your source model and target table structure (including indexes) and all 7 rows from source.
What type of SCD is it? Have you tried to use SCD Merge Wizard rather than SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Adding index on the WHERE condition column may resolve your issue. After adding index on the column, transactions will executes in faster way which reduce the chances of deadlock.